# Blank Variable in Array VBS

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I am new to VBS and I am trying to create an array from some variables gathered from a text file, however as a test when I try to echo out the array the first variable is blank and I have no idea why, perhaps there is something in VBS I'm not aware of, my code is as follows

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
objStartFolder = "filepath"
archivedCSV = "filepath"
xmlFolder = "filepath"
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(objStartFolder)
Set colFiles = objFolder.Files
For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
  if lcase(objFSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.Name)) = "csv" then
    origName = objFile.Name
    origPath = objFile.Path
    objFile.Name = "temp.txt"
    Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile(objStartFolder & "\temp.txt", 1)
    Dim callOffNo()
    Dim orderNo()
    n = 0
    Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream      
        strLine = objFile.ReadLine      
        arrFields = Split(strLine, ",") 
        If arrFields(0) <> "List of Call offs" Then
            If arrFields(0) <> "Call Off No" Then           
                If arrFields(2) <> currentOrder Then
                    currentOrder = arrFields(2)
                    ReDim orderNo(n)
                    orderNo(n) = arrFields(2)
                    n = n + 1
                End If          
            End If
        End If
    Loop    
    For Each order in orderNo
        MsgBox order
    Next
    objFile.Close
    newName = Replace(origName, objFSO.GetExtensionName(origPath), "")      
    archivedName = archivedCSV & "\" & origName
    tempFile = objStartFolder & "\temp.txt"     
    objFSO.MoveFile tempFile, archivedName  
  Exit for
 End if 
Next
```

The txt file looks like this

```
List of Call offs,,,,
Call Off No,Customer,Order Number,Item No,Quantity
12345,COMPANY,1013,1234,1
12345,COMPANY,1013,8652,1
12345,COMPANY,1013,4652,1
12345,COMPANY,1013,7203,1
12345,COMPANY,1013,3365,1
67891,COMPANY,1020,8963,2
67891,COMPANY,1020,1326,2
```

Therefore it should add two variables to the array: 1013, 1020. However the first MsgBox is blank and the second says 1020

I'm sure it's something simple that I am missing,

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please do **not** use `Dim arr()`. *EVER.* It creates an array without an actual size, which means just asking for trouble. If you need a dynamic array use `ReDim arr(-1)` for creating an empty array, or (better) use [`System.Collections.ArrayList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `Preserve` to 'grow' an array. A 'lonely' ReDim creates an array of empty slots; that's why your 'previous' elements are empty.